# Rails: Small Issue with <% if signed_in? %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently having an issue with <% if signed_in? %>.

When the user signs in, the **token is created** yet **none of the html changes** when:

**HTML**

```
<% if signed_in? %> 
<li><%= link_to "Post", "signup", :class=> "post main-button-color"  %></li> 
<li><%= link_to "Settings", "signup", :class=> "settings main-button"  %></li> 
<li><%= link_to "Sign Out", "signout", :class=> "signout main-button"  %></li> 
<% else %> 
<li><%= link_to "Sign Up", "signup", :class=> "signup main-button"  %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Sign In", "signin", :class=> "signin main-button" %></li> 
<% end %>
```

***EDIT***

**SessionsHelper**

```
def sign_in(user)
  remember_token = User.new_remember_token
  cookies[:remember_token] = {:value => remember_token, :expires => 8.hours.from_now} #or whenever
  user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.hash(remember_token))
  self.current_user = user
end

def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end

def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end

def current_user
  remember_token = User.hash(cookies[:remember_token])
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end

def sign_out
  self.current_user = nil
  cookies[:remember_token] = nil
end
```

**ApplicationController**

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
include SessionsHelper
```

**User Model**

```
before_save :create_remember_token

def User.new_remember_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def User.hash(token)
  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end

private

def create_remember_token
  self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
```

Everything still works when signing in, the remember token is saved in the browser cookies but still the HTML does not work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You have current_user method declared twice and differently. Maybe your methods override eachother?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to take it out, meant to - but the end result still is the same, the HTML does not switch over.

Comment: Is the page rendering the <% else %> block?

Comment: Yes, the page does render the 'else' block

Comment: Well, we know that `current_user` is returning nil. Double check your User table queries, make sure you don't have "auth_token" and "remember_token" mixed up somewhere.

Beyond that, you could try changing the DB store to plaintext, just to see if the tokens are being written to the DB in the right way.

Comment: @aerook I cleaned up some of the mess I made from the previous post above. Excuse the mess, I am coming back to rails from a 2 year break; I used some old code that mixed the auth and remember tokens. Also I changed up the code above. Everything seems to work and in the DB the remember token slot is filled after reseting it and entering a new user BUT the same issue still occurs. It is such a small problem but I just can't find the solution.

Comment: @Kellogs AHHA! Okay, so lets look at your `current_user` method. The remember_token is encrypted in the database. Your first line encrypts the remember_token from the browser, which is correct. On the next line, you are querying the User table using the raw, non-encrypted token, directly from the cookie.

Your query is: `User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])`. Change this to `User.find_by_remember_token(remember_token)`. At this point in the code, `remember_token` is the encrypted token from the cookie, which is what you should use to search.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing looks similar to [this](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#top), try poking around for an in-depth explanation.

It looks like your `signed_in?` method is correct. It doesn't look like you're doing anything with cookies or tokens in your `sign_in(user)` method, though.

As explained in the link, when a user signs in, you need to:

- Update the browser cookie with a session token
- Encrypt that session token and store it in the database
- Set the current signed in user to the user that just signed in

Your `current_user` method checks to see if there is an active user associated with the session. If there is, it gets returned. If not, it takes the browser's session token, encrypts it, and checks to see if any user has that current session token in the database. If so, that user is returned. If not, nil. This value is what is being checked by `signed_in?`. Because they are not being set properly, `current_user` returns nil, and the page acts as if the user is not signed in.

```
def sign_in(user)

    # Create a token
    auth_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64

    # Store the token in the browser
    cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = auth_token

    # Encrypt the token, store in database
    user.update_attribute(:auth_token, Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(auth_token))

    # Set current session's user
    self.current_user = user 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have followed the rails tutorial... So, when you sign in the user, you should assign a cookie value in order to fetch and check against it whether there is a user in accordance to that cookie.

In that term, you should change your sign_in method like this:

```
def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies[:remember_token] = {:value => remember_token, :expires => 8.hours.from_now} #or whenever
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
end
```

You are requesting the cookie, in current_user method, and checking it against the db, but you have nothing assigned to it...